# How can I prove that $\arcsin \left(\sqrt\frac{1 + \sin2x}{2} \right)= |x + \frac{\pi}{4}|$

Tags: real-analysis

the function $ f$ is defined as: $\arcsin \sqrt\frac{1 + \sin2x}{2}$
The function is defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Prove that $f(x) = |x + \frac{\pi}{4}|$ for all $x$ in $[\frac{-3\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}]$

We have for all in $ x \in \mathbb{R} $ :

$$f'(x) = \frac{\cos2x}{\sqrt{ \frac{3 - 2\sin2x - \sin^2 2x}{4}}} $$

I don't know how to proceed to prove that $f(x) = |x + \frac{\pi}{4}|$ for all $x$ in $[\frac{-3\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}]$

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like there's a square root missing somewhere.

Comment: When I compare the arcsine (lefthand side) with $|x+\pi/4|$ (righthand side) in desmos, the graphs don't match on a specific interval

Comment: @imranfat And they should not match.

Comment: @Dr.MV...yes I see it now, the square root is needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1+\sin(2x)}{2}&=\frac{\cos^2(x)+2\sin(x)\cos(x)+\sin^2(x)}{2}\\\\
&=\frac{(\sin(x)+\cos(x))^2}{2}\\\\
&=\frac{2\sin^2(x+\pi/4)}{2}
\end{align}$$

Can you proceed now?

Comment: $f'(x) = sin'(x + \frac{\Pi}{4}) = cos(x +\frac{\Pi}{4} ) $ How am I going have $f'(x) = |x +\frac{\Pi}{4}|$. Thank you.

Comment: $$\sqrt{\sin^2(x+\pi/4)}=?$$And $\arcsin(|\sin(\theta)|)=?$.

Comment: $ |cos (x + \pi / 4)|$.

Comment: No.  $\sqrt{\sin^2(x+\pi/4)}=|\sin(x+\pi/4)|$.

Comment: @De.MV. I'm sorry, yes. yes.

Comment: No worry.  Hope this was useful.